# How to overlay Navigator.NavBar?

Tags: react-native

How can I do overlay of Navigation.NavBar

Here what I have

[image: demo]

But I want Red one should overlay green one NavBar ?

Answer (score 0):

I made it using http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html#content
So I add there Navigator and it works as expected